# Why am I getting an error when trying to create class level array of structures in C#?

Tags: c#

I keep getting:

> Array initializers can only be used in a variable or field
>   initializer. Try using a new expression instead.

I have no idea why. Is this not possible with C#. A similar construct works with simple types such as int or float.

```
public struct UnitObject 
{
    public float    v;
    public string   t;
    public string   d;
}

public class UnitStandard
{
    public UnitObject[] UnitDict = new UnitObject[] { { 1f, "s", "s" } };
}
```

Using .NET 4.5.

Comment: How's `{ 1f, "s", "s" }` supposed to be converted to a `UnitObject`?

Comment: As in the same way you define an initialiser for an array of type int. A structure is just a new type with three implicit fields.

Comment: I don't think that `anonymous types == structs`.

Comment: Sorry Chaps my last point should have been.As in the same way you define an initialiser for an array of type int. A structure is just a new type with three implicit fields. Do I need a constructor for the structure. I'm sorry but I'm coming from a C background and I've been at this for nearly an hour now.

Comment: Additionally, mutable structs are usually [a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil) in C#. You should make the struct immutable or use a `class` instead.

Comment: Thanks Blorgbeard - will do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's not completely clear how you expect that to work, but in c#, it's not valid syntax. You have two options:

1. Use a constructor

   ```
   public struct UnitObject
   {
       public UnitObject(float v, string t, string d)
       {
           this.v = v;
           this.t = t;
           this.d = d;
       }
   }

   public UnitObject[] UnitDict = new UnitObject[] { new UnitObject(1, "s", "s") };
   ```
2. Use the object initializer

   ```
   public UnitObject[] UnitDict = new UnitObject[] 
   { 
       new UnitObject 
       { 
           v = 1, 
           t = "s", 
           d = "s" 
       } 
   };
   ```

As a side note: `v`, `t` and `d` are horrible names because they do not provide meaning and public members should follow PascalCase.

In order to follow the correct immutability pattern, use this:

```
public struct UnitObject
{
    public float V { get; private set; }
    public string T { get; private set; }
    public string D { get; private set; }

    public UnitObject(float v, string t, string d)
    {
        V = v;
        T = t;
        D = d;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers Camilo your last comment really helped. I tried a constructor after another search on the web. After hacking around a bit I got a solution - but yours is the better implementation. The names are just for experimentation. Thanks.

Comment: @cdcdcd Glad that it helped. I made an edit to reflect what Blorgbeard commented

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question here as I was advised this was the best way to help others - rather than editing the question.

I got this to work by adding a constructor:

```
public struct UnitObject 
{
    public float    v;
    public string   t;
    public string   d;

    public UnitObject(float val, string s1, string s2)
    {
       v = val; t = s1; d = s2;
     }
}

public class UnitStandard
{
    public UnitObject[] UnitDict = new UnitObject[] { new UnitObject( 1f, "s", "s" ) };
}
```

But Camilo's answer is much more elegant of course.